# DataGrid with footer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I search a solution to create DataGrid with footer, I found some idea to do that with avanced DataGrid but it's look like very hard.

So do you know  a simple solution for a footer on DataGrid.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by a DataGrid with a footer?  What type of footer do you want?  Can you not just position some component for your footer display below the DataGrid?

Comment: I'd like to add footer to display total of some columns. Thanks

Comment: Frankly, a footer is not required. You should add a label or whatever BELOW the datagrid which will show your total or whatever

Comment: I'm agree but by boss wants a footer like excel tab and not a label below the datagrid!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question during my own problem with dataGrid footer yesterday.
Since then I managed to solve it, and since there is no answer (I am aware that this is an old question), and someone might still need a solution, I'll post it here.

End result should be something like this:
http://prntscr.com/5cka32

Let's start:

First to provide footer support, we need to create a **DataGridFooterBase** class that extends UIComponent.
Add two properties (visibleColumns:Array and footerItemsChanged:Boolean) to it that belong to mx_internal namespace (I decided that only system needs to be able to see them).

```
public class DataGridFooterBase extends UIComponent
{
    mx_internal var visibleColumns:Array;
    mx_internal var footerItemsChanged:Boolean;

    public function DataGridFooterBase()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

Next, we will create the actual **DataGridFooter** class, which will extend **DataGridFooterBase** class.
Basically, this class will receive an *ICollection* dataProvider in which are objects that will be displayed in footer. Imagine this scenario, you have a grid in which information about invoices are present. You need to display a sum of all invoices beneath the amount*price column.
However, invoices can have different currencies (euros and dollars), and you need to display sums by currencies. That's why we have a dataProvider of *ICollection* type, which will represent rows and columns.

```
public class DataGridFooter extends DataGridFooterBase
{
    protected var dataGrid:Grid;
    protected var footerItems:Array=[];
    protected var cachedFooterHeight:Number=0;
    protected var cachedPaddingBottom:Number=0;
    protected var cachedPaddingTop:Number=0;

    private var _dataProvider:Object;

    public var leftOffset:Number=0;
    public var topOffset:Number=0;
    public var rightOffset:Number=0;
    public var bottomOffset:Number=0;

    public function DataGridFooter()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
    {
        if (value != null && !(value is ArrayCollection))
            value=new ArrayCollection([value]);
        _dataProvider=value;
        footerItemsChanged=true;
    }

    public function get dataProvider():Object
    {
        return _dataProvider;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        dataGrid=parent as Grid;
    }
}
```

This is a basic setup. Next we need to implement **measure()** and **updateDisplayList()** methods.
They will ensure that everything is nice and tidy.
So lets override these 2 methods:

```
override protected function measure():void
{
    super.measure();
    cachedFooterHeight=dataGrid._explicitFooterHeight ? dataGrid.footerHeight : 22;
    cachedPaddingBottom=getStyle("paddingBottom");
    cachedPaddingTop=getStyle("paddingTop");
    measuredHeight=cachedFooterHeight;
}

override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
{
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.beginFill(0xCFCFCF);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x696969);
    graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
    graphics.lineTo(unscaledWidth, 0);
    graphics.endFill();
    updateFooterItemsLayout();
}
```

If you're wondering what's with **graphics**, I use it to color the Footer, to make it different from dataGrid rows. After that we need to override **commitProperties()** method in which we check if dataProvider was changed. If it was, we need to redraw all the footer elements before updating display list (otherwise there will be performance issues)

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();
    if (footerItemsChanged)
    {
        footerItemsChanged=false;
        clearListItems();
        var cols:Array=visibleColumns;
        if ((cols && cols.length > 0 || dataGrid.footerVisible))
        {
            if (_dataProvider != null)
            {
                for (var j:int=0; j < _dataProvider.length; j++)
                {
                    addListItems(j, dataProvider.getItemAt(j));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                addListItems(0, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's continue, everything to this point was preparation, now we need actual methods that will add and remove *IListItemRenderer* objects to our new **Footer**.
So let's create 2 methods, **addListItems()** and **removeListItems()**

```
private function addListItems(row:int=0, data:Object=null):void
{
    if (footerItems == null)
        return;
    var cols:Array=visibleColumns;
    footerItems[row]=[];
    var rowData:DataGridListData;
    var item:IListItemRenderer;
    var colNum:int=0;
    var column:GridColumn;
    while (cols && colNum < cols.length)
    {
        column=cols[colNum];
        item=ObjectUtil.copy(column.cachedFooterRenderer) as IListItemRenderer;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item=new DataGridItemRenderer();
            item.styleName=column;
            column.cachedFooterRenderer=item;
        }
        var label:String="";
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (column.labelFunction == null)
                label=String(AbcUtils.findValueInObject(data, column.dataField.split(".")));
            else
                label=String(column.labelFunction(data, column));
            if (label == null || label == "null" || label == "NaN")
                label="";
        }
        rowData=new DataGridListData(label, column.dataField, colNum, uid, dataGrid, 0);
        if (item is IDropInListItemRenderer)
            IDropInListItemRenderer(item).listData=rowData;
        item.data=column;
        item.visible=true;
        addChild(DisplayObject(item));
        footerItems[row][colNum]=item;
        colNum++;
    }
}

private function clearListItems():void
{
    if (footerItems == null)
        return;
    for (var rows:int=0; rows < footerItems.length; rows++)
    {
        var cols:Array=footerItems[rows];
        for (var i:int=0; i < cols.length; i++)
        {
            removeChild(DisplayObject(cols[i]));
        }
    }
    footerItems.splice(0, footerItems.length);
}
```

What these two methods basically do, they take all visible columns and create a **DataGridItemRenderer** for each item in dataProvider collection (footerItems[row][column]), and add them to display list of our Footer class, or remove them. Last method that we need in this class will ensure that all items are positioned correctly, based on the column they "belong" to.

```
private function updateFooterItemsLayout():void
{
    if (_dataProvider == null || footerItems == null || footerItems.length == 0)
        return;
    for (var row:int=0; row < _dataProvider.length; row++)
    {
        var cols:Array=visibleColumns;
        var item:IListItemRenderer;
        var colNum:int=0;
        var ww:Number=0;
        var xx:Number=0;
        var column:GridColumn;
        while (cols && colNum < cols.length)
        {
            column=cols[colNum];
            item=footerItems[row][colNum];
            item.explicitWidth=ww=column.width;
            UIComponentGlobals.layoutManager.validateClient(item, true);
            item.setActualSize(ww, item.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight());
            if (row == 0)
                item.move(xx, cachedPaddingTop);
            else
                item.move(xx, item.height * row + cachedPaddingTop);
            xx+=ww;
            colNum++;
        }
    }
}
```

And basically that's it. Now we need to adjust our DataGrid, and DataGridColumn classes to connect with our new Footer class.

---

So let's continue with **DataGrid** class. We need to create a new Grid class which will extend DataGrid class.

```
public class Grid extends DataGrid
{
    public function Grid()
    {
        super();
    }

    //==== footer specific stuff =======
    protected var footer:DataGridFooterBase;
    mx_internal var footerClass:Class=DataGridFooter;
    private var _enableFooter:Boolean;
    private var _footerHeight:int=22;
    mx_internal var _explicitFooterHeight:Boolean;

    mx_internal function get dataGridFooter():DataGridFooterBase
    {
        return footer;
    }

    [Bindable("enableFootersChanged")]
    [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="false")]
    public function get enableFooters():Boolean
    {
        return _enableFooter;
    }

    public function set enableFooters(value:Boolean):void
    {
        if (value == _enableFooter)
            return;
        _enableFooter=enabled;
        invalidateDisplayList();
        dispatchEvent(new Event("enableFootersChanged"));
    }

    mx_internal function get footerVisible():Boolean
    {
        return enableFooters && (footerHeight > 0) && footer != null;
    }

    [Bindable("resize")]
    [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="22")]
    public function get footerHeight():Number
    {
        return _footerHeight;
    }

    public function set footerHeight(value:Number):void
    {
        _footerHeight=value;
        _explicitFooterHeight=true;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    public function setFooterValues(value:Object):void
    {
        if (footer != null)
            DataGridFooter(footer).dataProvider=value;
    }
    //==========================================

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        if (enableFooters && footer == null)
        {
            footer=new footerClass();
            addChild(footer);
        }
    }

    override public function invalidateDisplayList():void
    {
        super.invalidateDisplayList();
        if (footer != null)
        {
            footer.invalidateSize();
            footer.invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        if (footer != null)
        {
            footer.visibleColumns=visibleColumns;
            footer.invalidateSize();
            footer.validateNow();
        }
        if (footerVisible && verticalScrollBar && verticalScrollBar.visible)
        {
            var maxHeight:Number=this.verticalScrollBar.height - this.footer.height;
            verticalScrollBar.setActualSize(verticalScrollBar.width, maxHeight);
        }
    }

    override protected function adjustListContent(unscaledWidth:Number=-1, unscaledHeight:Number=-1):void
    {
        super.adjustListContent(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        var refY:Number=header.height;
        var additionalReservedHeight:Number=0;
        additionalReservedHeight+=footerVisible ? footerHeight : 0;
        listContent.setActualSize(listContent.width, listContent.height - additionalReservedHeight);
        refY+=listContent.height;
        if (footerVisible)
        {
            footer.move(listContent.x, refY);
            footer.setActualSize(listContent.width, footerHeight);
            refY+=footer.height;
        }
    }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();
        var additionalReservedHeight:Number=0;
        if (enableFooters)
            additionalReservedHeight+=footerHeight;
        this.measuredHeight=header.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight() + additionalReservedHeight + (rowHeight * rowCount) + viewMetrics.bottom + viewMetrics.top;
        this.measuredMinHeight=header.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight() + additionalReservedHeight + (rowHeight * rowCount) + viewMetrics.bottom + viewMetrics.top;
    }
}
```

I believe this class is more or less self explanatory. To set values to Footer you need to use **setFooterValues()** function, you can use a single object or an *ICollection* of objects. Another thing you need to do, if you expect to have more than one row in your footer, you need to explicitly set **footerHeight** property (or modify **measure()** method in Footer class to auto scale based on number of items in collection).

And the last thing we need is to modify **DataGridColumn** class, add a storage for *IListItemRenderer*.
Here it is:

```
public class GridColumn extends DataGridColumn
{
    mx_internal var cachedFooterRenderer:IListItemRenderer;

    public function GridColumn(columnName:String=null)
    {
        super(columnName);
    }
}
```

And that's it. Hope this helps someone and that it wasn't TL;DR; :)
Cheers.

Comment: I am sorry about that, unfortunately I don't work with AS3 anymore, so I can't make a new screen.